# Containing div should equal contents, but it's adding extra height

Tags: css

this is my code, and it works fine in JSfiddle:

```
 .signup_form{
              margin: 0 auto;
              width: 40%;
              min-width: 320px;
}

.signup_form_button_row {
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            background: yellow;
            width: 100%;
            clear: both;
}

#signup_submit_button {
              color: white;
              padding: 2.4% 5%;
              font-weight: 700;
              font-size: 16px;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              width: 40%;
              display: block;
              border: none;
              border-radius: 0;
              margin: 0 auto;
              background-color: orange;
              text-align: center;
              width: 100%;
}
```

however, on my actual site, the containing div (signup_form_bottom_row) adds extra height, when it should just be equal to its contents (signup_submit_button).

[image]

if anyone can help me figure out what's causing this extra height, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you've created a fiddle and it's ok then something else on your site is breaking this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `&nbsp;` between `#e2ma_signup_submit_button` and `#e2ma_signup_reset_button` with wrapping white space.  If you remove the non-breaking space, the gap disappears.  This is because the first button is set to `100%` width.  `100%` element plus a non-breaking space will drop the non-breaking space to a new line where it will add height to your container.

Comment: Thanks. it's an embedded form, and didn't catch that still being there. Much appreciated.